# How to add the class to the item you click on?

Tags: jquery

I have a list "abc". by default, the first one is selected.  If I click on the menu3, it should be set to "current", and menu1 'current' class should be removed.  Please help me to write this query using jQuery.

```
<ul class="abc">
    <li><a href="#" class="current">menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now there is one thing here: clicking on a and clicking on li is different!

Comment: When you click on `<a>` use `$(this).parent('li')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var anchors = $('li a');

anchors.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    anchors.removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8R6X/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.abc a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.abc a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NfcPF/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.abc a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.abc a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
- http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/KDULM/